# How to not display directory information and library members when running SAS University on windows 10 ( linux red hat)

Tags: sas

I am running the following autoexec before calling a macro. I usually just have the output go to the default window so I am not specifying html or pdf in the code itself although it is listed in the preferences.

```
AUTOEXEC.SAS
%LET sasworklocation="/folders/myfolders/";
ODS LISTING GPATH=&sasworklocation; 
/* ODS STATEMENTS */
ods path reset; 
ods _ALL_ close; 
ods trace off;
ods listing; 
ods noptitle; 
ods graphics on;

*INITIALIZATION 
proc printto; run;
```

I am following the autoexec with call to a macro but I suspect that the macro itself initiates the dir info and lib member output. That is what is happening on the code I am working with. The macro inputs data.

A display of unwanted dir info and lib members appear in the results window. How can I stop that from happening when running SAS University? It greatly increases output size.

Macro call is as follows:

```
%let mtitle=%str(GLOMERULONEPHROPATHY SEVERITY);
title1 &mtitle;
%let noGroup=4;
%let codeno=5;
%let one=Group1;
data DataFile;
input severity $ Group1-Group&noGroup  @@;
one=&one;
cards;
none      05  05  07  04
minimum   20  25  16  13
mild      21  13  18  13
moderate  16  14  12  14
severe    10  15  19  28
;
%ridits(DataFile,&noGroup,&codeno,.05,No,&mtitle,&one);
```

I think the problem is in the data import. How should I do that?

I don't want to output to pdf or rtf for simplicity. I just want to open sas studio /sas university, code, and get output to the screen.

By the way, why am I not getting an output window as well?

Thanks.  MM

[image: toc output]

Comment: You have two ODS LISTING statements - one will overwrite the other. I have no idea what you're seeing or what's happening here with the code shown nothing should be th issue. You'll have to provide a screenshot of what you mean by ToC and what the macro code is that's causing that. ODS HTML5 is the default output so try specifying the GPATH using that statement instead.

Comment: Reeza.  How do I add a screenshot?

Comment: Take the screenshot on your computer and save it somewhere. To add to here, see the picture icon - looks like mountains or the 6th icon. That allows you to add a picture.

Comment: Reeza, Where on the screen will I see a picture icon? I don't see it anywhere?  MM

Comment: In the editor. Edit your question and hover over each icon to see the meaning if you’re not sure.

Comment: I found the picture icon although I could only successfully add one picture. Am I supposed to be able to add more?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a proc datasets command which appeared in one of my runs in the directory information table. Add the NOLIST option to the PROC DATASETS statement to avoid the extra output.

```
proc datasets nolist;
...
```

An alternate way is to use PROC DELETE to delete a dataset.

```
proc delete data=work.XXX; run;
```

The CONTENTS statement inside of PROC DATASETS can generate PROC CONTENTS output also.